# Toggling visibility of next table row with checkbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 15 form elements on my page in the following format:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="fieldset-table-field-3-span">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExistingProductId_MappingName_IsFreeText)
  </td>
</tr>
```

When the checkbox is in the checked state, I would like the next row to be visible:

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="3" class="fieldset-table-field-3-span">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExistingProductId_MappingName_FreeText)
   </td>
</tr>
```

I could write some JS/jQuery to hide the rows and toggle them on click, but wondered if anybody had a solution for toggling the state of the "next control" so I could hook it up to each checkbox in my form thus only having to do this once in order to adhere to DRY.

Here's the markup from the first couple of rows:

```
    <table class="fieldset-table" align="center" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>
            <td class="fieldset-table-label">
                <label for="ExistingProductId_MappingName">Existing ID</label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" class="fieldset-table-field-3-span">
                <select id="ExistingProductId_MappingName" name="ExistingProductId_MappingName"><option value="">-- Not Mapped --</option>
                <option value="Id">Id</option>
                <option value="Name">Name</option>
                <option value="Cost Price">Cost Price</option>
                <option value="Unit Price">Unit Price</option>
                </select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ExistingProductId_MappingName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fieldset-table-label">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" class="fieldset-table-field-3-span">
                <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Free text field is required." id="ExistingProductId_MappingName_IsFreeText" name="ExistingProductId_MappingName_IsFreeText" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="ExistingProductId_MappingName_IsFreeText" type="hidden" value="false" />
                <label for="ExistingProductId_MappingName_IsFreeText">Free text</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fieldset-table-label">
                <label for="ExistingProductId_MappingName_FreeText">Text value</label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" class="fieldset-table-field-3-span">
                <input class="text-box single-line" id="ExistingProductId_MappingName_FreeText" name="ExistingProductId_MappingName_FreeText" type="text" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: could we see more markup? especially your checkboxes.

Comment: Sure. Let me paste the output from the Razor page. Will update the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the last change() call is to handle when the page is first loaded (i.e. if the checkbox starts unchecked, the next row is hidden.) Not sure if you need that, but I usually end up needing to use it in situations like these.

```
  $(function(){
    $('input.check-box[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
      $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    }).change();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand your question (never delved into ASP before) but here's what I'd do to make the next element visible when a checkbox is clicked, using jQuery 1.7.x:

```
$(function(){

    $('yourCheckbox').on('change', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) //if this box is checked
        {
            $(this).parents('tr').next('tr').show(); 
            //show the <tr> elem that comes after the current one 
        }
    });
});
```

again sorry if I've got this backwards. 
Other thing is there is no difference between your first 2 HTML snippets, why is that?

Hope this helps anyway

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jammypeach. I went with Chris Baclig's answer as it handles the initial hiding of the text field too.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/DQZah/9/

```
$('input.check-box').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('tr').next().fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').next().fadeOut('fast');
    }
});​
```

Basically get the closest tr on check then show it :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I went with Chris Baclig's answer as it handles the initial hiding of the text field too.

Comment: http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/067/705/okaytemplate.PNG?1318992465